# how dragged image with a min and max value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, draggable

I have this code for increase height of a image.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    touchStart = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.image];
    touchStart2 = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.tableView];
    isResizingLR = ( self.image.bounds.size.height - touchStart.y < kResizeThumbSize );
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.image];
    CGPoint previous=[[touches anyObject]previousLocationInView:self.image];

    float  deltaWidth = touchPoint.x-previous.x;
    float  deltaHeight = touchPoint.y-previous.y;


    if (isResizingLR) {

        self.image.frame = CGRectMake(self.image.frame.origin.x, self.image.frame.origin.y, self.image.frame.size.width, touchPoint.y + deltaWidth);
        self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x ,self.tableView.frame.origin.y + deltaHeight,  self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height - deltaHeight );
        self.viewTitle.frame = CGRectMake(self.viewTitle.frame.origin.x ,self.viewTitle.frame.origin.y + deltaHeight,  self.viewTitle.frame.size.width, self.viewTitle.frame.size.height);
    }
}
```

I want put a condition for a minimHeight =100 and  maximHeight =300;
How can i do that?
I already try this :

```
if (isResizingLR) {

        if (self.image.frame.size.height >100 && self.image.frame.size.height <300) {
        self.image.frame = CGRectMake(self.image.frame.origin.x, self.image.frame.origin.y, self.image.frame.size.width, touchPoint.y + deltaWidth);
        self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x ,self.tableView.frame.origin.y + deltaHeight,  self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height - deltaHeight );
        self.viewTitle.frame = CGRectMake(self.viewTitle.frame.origin.x ,self.viewTitle.frame.origin.y + deltaHeight,  self.viewTitle.frame.size.width, self.viewTitle.frame.size.height);
        }
    }
```

but every time after dragged image at: self.image.frame.size.height =100 or 300, i can't resize image. He need to be draggable all time!
Thank you!

EDIT:
I don't want resize image when heightImage is 100.

My original height of image is 200. My user can click and resize image how he want, but no over 300 and less than 100. I just put a minimum and maximum height. I hope you understand now.

Comment: "but every time when self.image.frame.size.height =100 or 300, i can't resize image. […] EDIT: I don't want resize image when heightImage is 100." ???

Comment: Is just a example.
Image need to be draggable every time, but with a minimum and maximum dimensions(value). After increase height at 300, i can't resize at 200 for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

```
int aux=touchPoint.y + deltaWidth;
if (aux>300) {
            aux=300;
        }
        else if(aux<100){
            aux=100;
        }
 self.image.frame = CGRectMake(self.image.frame.origin.x, self.image.frame.origin.y, self.image.frame.size.width, aux);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to test `<=` and `>=`?

```
if (self.image.frame.size.height >= 100 && self.image.frame.size.height <= 300) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: EDIT: I don't want resize image when heightImage is 100.

My original height of image is 200. My user can click and resize image how he want, but no over 300 and less than 100. I just put a minimum and maximum height. I hope you understand now.